# Iphone Apps Hiding

Tags: iphone

I want to make some of my applications icons invisible,
and using password or something to make it visible/invisible.

Any suggestions how to make it? the reason is to block some of the iPhone content such as economics and business apps from children and etc.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this. If you are talking about your own apps (ie ones you have developed) then you'll have to put the password protection on entry to the app. If you're talking about hiding any other apps, then this is not something a third party developer can do, it would be an OS level function.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the access to any application by turning on *Restrictions*:

- Start the *Settings* app
- Go to *General* / *Restrictions*
- Tap *Enable Restrictions*
- Enter a password
- Select the restricted apps

But I guess this question doesn't really belong here.

Comment: Hah, I've been on SO too much lately... I mentally added "how to do this programmatically?" to the end of the question!